# How to avoid or delay extra work on cache miss

Tags: go, caching

Is there a suggested pattern to mitigate known cache misses? I have a map being populated with the response from an API call over the network. There should be almost no cache misses as this data rarely changes. On each cache miss I make an API call. How can I (in Golang or in general) avoid spamming the API endpoint? (this happens when data is missing and will never be there or won't be there for a long time, i.e. always missing the cache). Would there need to be some sort of delayed calls for previous misses (like back off or ...)?

Comment: You can simply cache nil for the cache key to store a miss

Comment: But I would need to expire this value over some time as I don't know when in the future this key may have the valid value.

Comment: In that case, store a special type of record meaning it is a cache miss, and also store a timestamp showing when it was inserted. If it was inserted before a certain time, remove it from the cache and call the API

Comment: you need a circuit breaker for the http client with exponential backoff configured.

Comment: Thank you @ArjunKR! I see https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sony/gobreaker has an implementation I could probably use.